# How to filter out subarrays which contain NaN's?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume an array of shape `(n,5,2)` which contains `NaN`s at random places, generated by the following code:

```
n = 10
arr = np.random.rand(n, 5, 2)

# replace some values by nan
arr = arr.ravel()
index_array = np.arange(arr.size)
np.random.shuffle(index_array)
arr[index_array[:5]] = np.nan
arr = arr.reshape(n, 5, 2)
```

How can I efficiently filter this array such that only those `arr[i]`s are kept which don't contain `NaN`s? The resulting shape would then be `(m,5,2)` with `m<=n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to reshape anything:

```
has_nans = np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(-1,-2))
has_nans 
array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> arr = arr[~has_nans]
>>> arr.shape
(6, 5, 2)
```

Older versions of numpy you will need to do something like the following:

```
has_nans = np.isnan(arr).any(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
```

Comment: D'you know, I don't think I knew you could use `-2` this way.  Neat!

Comment: This is nice, thanks for the hint on the older numpy versions, I actually needed that!

Answer (score 0):

This is a 1 liner:

```
new = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any((-1,-2))]

print new.shape
Out[10]: (5, 5, 2)
```