# Regression line and fitted curve for scatter plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a large dataset I'm looping through to generate plots from. I have successfully figured out the scatter plots, but I'm having issues figuring out how to generate a regression line and fitted curve.

Here is my code:

```
# import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# OPTIONS AND PARAMETERES
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
df = pd.read_csv('W:/Dropbox/Connor/vaccinia.csv', index_col = 'SampleID')
x = df.iloc[0][59:84].astype(np.float)
fileNameTemplate = r'W:\Dropbox\Connor\Plot\Plot{0:2}.png'

# THE LOOP - for i in df.count(1):
for i in range(0, 10):
    venus = df.iloc[i][8:33]
    mcherry = df.iloc[i][33:58]   

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(str(i) + " - " + df.iloc[i][0])
    plt.xlabel('uM compound')
    plt.ylabel('reporter activity')
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.set_xscale('log')
    ax1.scatter(x, venus, c='g')
    ax1.scatter(x, mcherry, c='r')

    plt.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(i))
    plt.close()
```

I've found (and attempted) multiple approaches online to no avail. The regression line usually fails when I get an attribute error for `np.sin` and the fitted curve won't work because of errors during `polyfit`. I suspect some of the problem might be because some of my data points are `NaN`.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: I would also appreciate your thoughts on best practices - I started learning python and all of this today so I don't really know what I'm doing yet.

Comment: your question is very vague. Try to refine your question to obtain better answers. SO is not so much for discussing.

Comment: OK, how do I get np.sin not to throw attribute errors or polyfit to work properly?

Comment: The big thing here is that your example needs to be copy/pastable. In its current form, I can't run your example code since I don't have access to your W:\ drive. Please include some code in your example to generate some mockup of your data.

Comment: what is the error message and what code snippet produces it? your code seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

for fitting data to a curve, I used [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit)

for filtering your data, to remove NaNs, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860262/how-to-filter-out-subarrays-which-contain-nans) answer